# Bootstrap 4 nested responsive table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. I have a table within a table that I would like to be responsive.

In reality all of it is one table, but I only want the second column and on to be scrollable. The only way I could think to get this to work was to make a nested table with everything from the second column onwards being in its own `table-response` div. However this is not working and the responsiveness only happens if I make the entire table response.

I'll show you what I have and maybe we can work to figure out how to make my mess responsive, but if it's possible to make a table where only the second column onwards scrolls on the x axis that would be awesome. I'm really stumped here. I would like the table with id `wannabe-responsive` to be scrollable, but the first table with id `not-responsive` to stay put.

```css
.item {
  min-height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="item mx-5 mt-2" style="overflow: hidden">
    <h2 class="p-2 bg-primary text-white">Inventory</h2>
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">Time Chart</h3>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="p-0">
            <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="p-4"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Potatoes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Apples</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Corn</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lettuce</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td class="container p-0">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                <thead>
                  <th>1:20</th>
                  <th>1:52</th>
                  <th>2:30</th>
                  <th>3:17</th>
                  <th>3:35</th>
                  <th>4:22</th>
                  <th>4:45</th>
                  <th>5:15</th>
                  <th>6:15</th>
                  <th>6:30</th>
                  <th>7:25</th>
                  <th>7:37</th>
                  <th>7:50</th>
                  <th>8:02</th>
                  <th>8:15</th>
                  <th>8:27</th>
                  <th>8:40</th>
                  <th>8:52</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Edit:** I found that adding the `container` class to the `<td>` container the response table does make it responsive but I'm still having issues with the data overflowing outside the rop level container. I'll update as I make progress

**Edit 2**: Please check out my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b54v9t6w/2/) to see my progress. I almost have it working exactly how I want, but I'm still having an issue with the content getting cut short. If you run the fiddle you will see that it scrolls how I want, but it cuts off the time slots at the end, and the end of the scroll bar as well, depending on how small the screen is. My ultimate solution would for it to show the entire scroll bar at the bottom at all times, and for all of the time slots to be viewable when scrolling.

Right now it looks like this
[image: Demo]

See how both the end time slots and scroll bar are cut off? I'm so close! Any help is super super appreciated!

Comment: So you need the second table with values 1 2 3 etc to be scrollable horizontally?

Comment: @Α.Papadakis yes, that is the goal. I did just figure out that adding the `container` class to the `td` with the responsive table makes it responsive though! I literally just discovered this though, so I will tinker with it and update my question or answer if I find a good solution. Please feel free to build on this and see if you can find a better way though.

Comment: Ok update your code! I suppose tha this is a sample, not the actual data, because I can't see the necessity of this functionallity.

Comment: @Α.Papadakis please see Edit 2 to see my current progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to nest so many tables because it's dificult to handle the responsive design. I replaced the left table with `flex` and I removed the outer table. Here is the fix:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style type="text/css">
 .item {
  min-height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2
 }

 .names {
  padding: 50px 0 34px;
 }

 .names > div {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
 }

 .table td {
  height: 50px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="item mx-5 mt-2" style="overflow: hidden">
   <h2 class="p-2 bg-primary text-white">Inventory</h2>
   <div class="text-center">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">Time Chart</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="d-flex p-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between names pr-2">
     <div>Potatoes</div>
     <div>Apples</div>    
     <div>Corn</div>
     <div>Lettuce</div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
      <thead>
       <th>1:20</th>
       <th>1:52</th>
       <th>2:30</th>
       <th>3:17</th>
       <th>3:35</th>
       <th>4:22</th>
       <th>4:45</th>
       <th>5:15</th>
       <th>6:15</th>
       <th>6:30</th>
       <th>7:25</th>
       <th>7:37</th>
       <th>7:50</th>
       <th>8:02</th>
       <th>8:15</th>
       <th>8:27</th>
       <th>8:40</th>
       <th>8:52</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```